# Are the stabilizers of facets in a Bruhat-Tits building pairwise distincts?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, bruhat-tits-theory

Let $G$ be a reductive $p$-adic group and let $\mathcal B$ denote its Bruhat-Tits building. For $x \in \mathcal B$, denote by $\overline x$ the (closure of the) minimal facet containing $x$. We associate to $x$ the open compact subgroup $G_x$ consisting of all elements $g\in G$ such that $g\cdot \overline x = \overline x$.

Assume that for two points $x,y \in \mathcal B$, we have $G_x = G_y$. Is it true that $\overline x = \overline y$ ?

I think it is known that $G_x$ acts transitively on the set of all appartments in $\mathcal B$ which contain the facet $\overline x$. Thus, our assumption implies that $\overline x$ and $\overline y$ live in precisely the same appartments. However, I don't see how I could go further to prove the equality (assuming that it is true).

Comment: I don't have a good answer for this, but I just want to note that (a) I think this would be a good question for MathOverflow and (b) this may be the biggest cognitive gap I've ever had between the contents of a question and the questioner's icon. :-)

Comment: Hope Suzet will understand the point of taking relevant examples, instead of such an abstract non-sense.

Comment: @reuns Fair point. It was while working with a specific example that I was led to the question above. I couldn't work out the definitive answer with my example. So, I wanted to check whether it could have been a general "well known" fact on buildings instead. I'm still on it though !

Comment: Since you already know that $x$ and $y$ lie in the same apartment, you could conclude with the fact that hyperplanes separate facets (by definition). So if $H$ is a hyperplane in $\mathcal{A}$ with corresponding reflection $n_H$ (in the normalizer of the maximal split torus), then $x\in H$ if and only if $n_H\in G_x$. Hence, $G_x = G_y$ implies that $x$ and $y$ lie in the same facet.

Answer (score 1):

Once $x$ and $y$ are assumed to be in the standard apartment $\mathcal A$, the stabilizer is described in terms of root data (see [Rabinoff's book](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ejdr/papers/building.pdf)):
$$G_x:=\langle T(R),\mathfrak X_{\psi}:\psi\in\Psi,\psi(x)\ge0\rangle=\langle T(R),\mathfrak X_\alpha(\mathfrak p^{-\lfloor\alpha(x)\rfloor})\rangle,$$
where $\Psi:=\{\alpha+n:\alpha\in\Phi,n\in\mathbb Z\}$ are the affine roots, and $\mathfrak X_{\psi}=\{x_\alpha(t):t\in\mathfrak p^n\}$ where $x_\alpha\colon F\to G$ is a root. Thus, our goal now is to recover the $\lfloor \alpha(x)\rfloor$ from the group $G_x$. This is possible by intersecting with the standard parabolic subgroup $P$ corresponding to the root $\alpha$, via Propsition 3.10 of Rabinoff's boook.